# Thrift Compiler(0.9.3) Generates Function thrift.PrependError Which is Undefined In Thrift Package

Tags: go, compilation, thrift

I use `thrift` compiler (0.9.3) to generate gen-go folder, while the compiler generates a function `thrift.PrependError` which can't be found in `thrift` package (`git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift`).

Should I use `thrift` compiler (0.9.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend error was added in Thrift 0.9.3, and is present in the current codebase:

https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/53dd39833a08ce33582e5ff31fa18bb4735d6731/lib/go/thrift/exception.go

https://github.com/apache/thrift/commit/527b6d9c86a7e5cde14cbb09a0e3103be0791c3a#diff-d28b48f0840fec65d4a9ece357194970R32

If it isn't being found in your local library, you need to update your local (or vendored) version of Thrift.

Remember, your thrift generator binary (in `/usr/local/bin/thrift`) can be a different version than the package you have in your `$GOPATH`.  Always make sure you update the two together.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use thrift compiler (0.9.2)?

You should make sure and double-check **that the version of the Thrift compiler matches the version of the Thrift library** being used. The code generated by the Thrift compiler and the library code depend on each other, they are two pieces of the same puzzle. It does not matter what Thrift version you are using, as long as you are consistent.

Aside from that, the curent stable is 0.9.3, this is also the recommended version.